# C++ protect getters/setters using final

Tags: c++, encapsulation

Let's say I have a class that requires an encapsulated variable for conditional protection.

```cpp
class person {

private:
    int height_;

public:
    explicit person(int height) {
        this->height_ = height;
    }

    int get_height() const noexcept {
        return height_;
    }

    void set_height(int height) {
        if (height < 0)
            throw std::invalid_argument("Height cannot be negative");
        this->height_ = height;
    }
};
```

I realize I can just make height an unsigned int but it's an example of many possible problems.

Should my `set_height` be marked as `virtual` ... `final` to protect it against derived overriding?
Or should I just assume that under normal circumstances that won't happen?

As a side note does this increase compile time or have some negative connotation?

Comment: A virtual member function is only overridable under the class that declared it as virtual. It does not "propagate back" to bases. Any code that is handed a reference to `person` can only call *its* set/get member functions. There's no need to contort the code, just don't declare it virtual.

Comment: `if (height < 0)` why make it normal signed integer, use `unsigned` integer and avoid this check. In fact, you can avoid getters/setters that way by making the variable public.

Comment: Please use initializer list for your constructors. Creating default initialized members first and override them later is bad style and may take run time.

Comment: If the class invariant is that height cannot be negative, that should be checked in the constructor as well as the `set_height` mutator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only virtual functions can be overriden by a subclass.
As it is in your code a subclass wouldn't be able to override those functions anyways.

If you needed them to be virtual for some reason then yes, the final keyword would prevent overriding.